# Centos 7 , cant update kernel

Tags: centos, kernel, linux-kernel, hosting, centos-7

I am running centos-7(vm) on http://www.ovh.com/. My kernel version is 2.6.32-042stab108.8. Even after `yum clean all && yum update` and reboot. still kernel version is 2.6.32-042stab108.8. Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use the ELRepo release [2]

Warning a new Kernel may render your system unstable or unusable.

Assuming you are running on CentOS v7.0 not v7.1, then the stock kernel is reported to be 3.10.x so it is odd you are reporting v2.6.32.  [3] Also recommends using ElRepo's Kernal and has additional instructions for upgrading including to Kernel v3.17.x

**UPDATE:** 
OVH apparently uses custom kernels as mentioned here [4]

[1] http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-update-the-kernel-in-centos-red-hat/

[2] https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/200574/centos-7-1-still-using-outdate-kernel-3-10-how-to-upgrade-to-kernel-4-0

[3] http://wiki.mikejung.biz/CentOS_7#Upgrade_CentOS_7_Kernel_to_3.17

[4] http://change_ovh_kernel.onlinephpfunctions.com/

https://forum.ovh.us/showthread.php/2368-CentOS-7-with-kernel-version-gt-3-10